# Facing error while creating dataframe in loops

Tags: python, loops

This is my code:

```
models = data['ModelG'].unique()
#ModelG is the column where i have different brands, 'data' is my database

for i in models:
    datacut = data[data['ModelG']== models[i]]
# I want to make different dataframe by unique values in column m
```

How can I resolve the following error?

> Error: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
> numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: use loc to create a new record. key=len(df) df.loc[key,'field']=[a,b,c]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
models = data['ModelG'].unique()
#ModelG is the column where i have different brands, 'data' is my database

for i in models:
    datacut = data[data['ModelG']== i]
# I want to make different dataframe by unique values in column m
```